# Alignment does not work

Tags: javascript, html

```js
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>
```

```html
<p text-align="right" id="demo" style="font-family:Comic Sans MS; font-size:20px; color:#2E9AFE;"></p>
```

Its suppose to be displaying the time in my HTML website but it doesn't align in the right. 
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

```
text-align="right" not use directly
```

replace to your `p` tag

```
<p  id="demo" style="text-align:right; font-family:Comic Sans MS; font-size:20px; color:#2E9AFE;"></p>
```

Comment: yeah.. thank you for that... really appreciated... i am realy a begginer to this.. thanks .. Lalji Tadhani